# Narrowing conversion required while using a P-RNG

Tags: c++, random, compiler-errors, c++17, console-application

I am trying to get a random number between a minimum value and a maximum value, but i get a narrowing conversion error. I have checked the template parameters of uniform_int_distribution so using a short shouldnt be an issue.

> **Template parameters**
> IntType -   The result type generated by the generator. The effect is undefined if this is not one of *short*, *int*, *long*, *long long*, *unsigned short*, *unsigned int*, *unsigned long*, or *unsigned long long*.

In my attempt to fix the issue i casted the values to a short which did not seem to fix it.
When 2 integer values have been attributed to randX and randY the error disappeared.

My current code after reverting the changes that have been made to it:

```cpp
Fruit Fruit::getRandomFruit(const short& maxPosX, const short& maxPosY)
{
    bool isEaten{0};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randX{ 1, maxPosX-1 };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randY{ 1, maxPosY-1 };

    COORD frPos{randX(mersenne), randY(mersenne)};

    return {isEaten,
            frPos
    };
}
```

Error message:

```
Element '2': conversion from 'int' to '_Ty' requires a narrowing conversion
```

From my understanding the compiler sees the values as being integers and it's attempting to convert them.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` is an `int`, as numeric literals are `int` unless otherwise specified.

`maxPosX-1` and `maxPosY-1` are also `int`s, for historical C reasons.  Operators on integer types that are smaller than `int` produce `int` results.

Solution 1: Cast them to short.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randX{ short(1), short(maxPosX-1) };
std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randY{ short(1), short(maxPosY-1) };
```

Solution 2: Construct with `( )` instead of `{ }` to silence narrowing errors.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randX( 1, maxPosX-1 );
std::uniform_int_distribution<short> randY( 1, maxPosY-1 );
```